# Launching Bootstrap modal with Backbone

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, backbone.js, modal-dialog

Launching a Bootstrap modal with Backbone has proven to be a huge pain in the ass.

Here is what is in my HTML file:

```
<body>
<div id="teamSnapImportDiv"></div>
<script>

    function importFromTeamSnap(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        alert('agegage');
        var aimportTeamSnapView = new importTeamSnapView({el: $("#teamSnapImportDiv")});
        var rendered = aimportTeamSnapView.render();
        //$(rendered.el).appendTo(this.$el).hide().fadeIn().slideDown();
    };

</script>


<script type="text/html" id="teamsnap-import-template">

        <div class="modal fade">
            <div class="modal-dialog">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                        <h4 class="modal-title">Modal title</h4>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">
                        <p>One fine body&hellip;</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <button id="cancelTeamSnapImport" type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                        <button id="confirmTeamSnapImport" type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
                    </div>
                </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
            </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
        </div><!-- /.modal -->


</script>
</body>
```

here is my Backbone view:

```
var importTeamSnapView = Backbone.View.extend({
    tagName: "div",
    id: 'teamSnapImportDiv',
    initialize: function() {
    },
    render: function (){
        var importTeamSnapTemplate = document.getElementById('teamsnap-import-template').innerHTML;
        this.$el.html(_.template(importTeamSnapTemplate)());
    }
});
```

What on earth do I need to do to make this work? I can get other stuff to work, but the modal thing is not working. Other examples do not make it clear what needs to get done, or why.

Comment: You may need to manually show the modal for dynamically added elements using `$('#teamSnapImportDiv modal').modal()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this works great as a solution to the question.

http://awkward.github.io/backbone.modal/

unfortunately, it's yet another library, but it WORKS.

Answer (score -1):

Try using [this approach](https://gist.github.com/andrewshatnyy/6126879).

**Modal JS**

```
var BaseModalView = Backbone.View.extend({

    id: 'base-modal',
    className: 'modal fade hide',
    template: 'modals/BaseModal',

    events: {
      'hidden': 'teardown'
    },

    initialize: function() {
      _(this).bindAll();
      this.render();
    },

    show: function() {
      this.$el.modal('show');
    },

    teardown: function() {
      this.$el.data('modal', null);
      this.remove();
    },

    render: function() {
      this.getTemplate(this.template, this.renderView);
      return this;
    },

    renderView: function(template) {
      this.$el.html(template());
      this.$el.modal({show:false}); // dont show modal on instantiation
    }
 });
```

**Handlebars template**

```
<div class="modal-dialog">
  <div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">
      <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
      <h4 class="modal-title">Modal title</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
      ...
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
      <a href="#" class="btn">Close</a>
      <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</a>
    </div>
  </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
</div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
```

**Parent View**

```
modalView = new BaseModalView();
modalView.show();

// Modal view automatically bound to the body and removes itself on hidden;
```

Comment: yeah, I saw this example already, will try to work with it again, thanks